# How to get response string from Indy udp server?

Tags: udp, c++builder, indy

I'm trying to create a simple text exchange between Indy UDP client and server in C++ Builder 10.3.1. This is the code I use:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    IdUDPClient1->Send("Hello");
    UnicodeString resp = IdUDPClient1->ReceiveString();
    ShowMessage(resp);
}

void __fastcall TForm1::IdUDPServer1UDPRead(TIdUDPListenerThread *AThread,
    const TIdBytes AData, TIdSocketHandle *ABinding)
{
    UnicodeString req = BytesToString(AData);

    if(req == "Hello"){
        // why this don't work?
        ABinding->Send("Hello 2");

        // the following works if ThreadedEvent = true
        // AThread->Server->Send(ABinding->PeerIP, ABinding->PeerPort, "Hello 2");
    }
}
```

I am unable to get the response from the server on the client side. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the server side, the provided `TIdSocketHandle` in the `OnUDPRead` event is not "connected" (from the OS's perspective) to the peer that sent the received data, so by default calling`ABinding->Send()` *requires* specifying the target IP/Port to send to.  That is why `ABinding->Send(ABinding->PeerIP, ABinding->PeerPort, "Hello 2");` works and `ABinding->Send("Hello 2");` does not.

Calling `ABinding->Send()` is not dependant on the server's `ThreadedEvent` property in *any* way.  That property merely controls whether the server's `OnUDPRead` event is triggered in the context in the main UI thread or not. It has *no effect* on how the server allocates and manages its sockets.

However, if the server's `ThreadedEvent` property is false, and the client and server are running in the same app process, the server won't be able to fire its `OnUDPRead` event while your `Button1Click()` is running. You will need to set `ThreadedEvent` to true in that situation so the `OnUDPRead` event is triggered in the context of a worker thread instead, not waiting on the main UI thread.

Otherwise, move the client to its own worker thread instead.

Answer (score 1):

Hope you can accept an answer in Delphi. I can not translate it just now.

With a pair of projects, `VclIdUDPServer` and `VclIdUDPClient`, as follows, I get the two to communicate. Tested on same machine as well as on two machines. Note, that this is minimal code to get the two to chat.

`VclIdUDPServer`

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  Binding: TIdSocketHandle;
begin
  Binding := IdUDPServer1.Bindings.Add;
  Binding.IP := '192.168.2.109';
  Binding.Port:= 49000;
  IdUDPServer1.OnUDPRead:= IdUDPServer1UDPRead;
  IdUDPServer1.Active:=True;
end;

procedure TForm1.IdUDPServer1UDPRead(AThread: TIdUDPListenerThread;
  const AData: TIdBytes; ABinding: TIdSocketHandle);
var
  req: string;
begin
  req := BytesToString(AData);
  Memo2.Lines.Add(req);
  if req = 'Hello' then
    ABinding.SendTo(ABinding.PeerIP, ABinding.PeerPort, 'Yes sir!', ABinding.IPVersion);
  end;
end;
```

`VclIdUDPClient`

```
procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  IdUDPClient1.Host:='192.168.x.xxx'; // set to your ip
  IdUDPClient1.Port:=49000;
  IdUDPClient1.Active:=True;
end;

procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  rep: string;
begin
  IdUdpClient1.Send('Hello');
  rep := IdUdpClient1.ReceiveString();
  Memo1.Lines.Add(rep);
end;
```

Comment: Yes. This works if client & server are in separate applications. When tested together in the same application the client timeouts waiting for the response. Why?

Comment: I guess there's a port/address conflict, I tried using `ReuseSocket` but it did not help. Perhaps separate threads would help. Is this a real situation or an academic question. You might want to ask a new question specifically about using server and client, talking to each other in the same application.

Comment: @TomBrunberg there is no IP/port conflict in this example. The client binds to an ephemeral IP/port by default. That IP/port is reported by the `ABinding` on the server side. Sending back to the `ABinding.PeerIP/PeerPort` is the correct thing to do.

Comment: @Tracer see the answer I posted